# Moving Files in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to move a file in C++ and can't find a solution, this is the line so far:
`system("move \"C:\\Users\\exampleuser\\Desktop\\Test.docx" "C:\\Users\\exampleuser\\OneDrive\\examplefolder""");`
Is there anything wrong with the Syntax or string as the code compiles but cannot find directory.

Comment: **DO NOT** use `system` to do something simple like move files. Use [`std::rename()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename). Every single `system()` call is potentially a planet-destroying vulnerability unless you take *extreme* care to protect yourself from shell injections. They should be avoided unless there is absolutely no alternative.

Comment: In addition, the recent C++ Standards [have a library full of really neat filesystem manipulation functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) you may be able to put to use.

Comment: In this case, then how would I use ```std::rename()```?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use OneDrive. If I'm not mistaken, it works via a Windows shell extension, which won't work at the command line. Using the [OneDrive API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/upload?view=odsp-graph-online) is pretty easy though. [IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) would probably also work.

Comment: @Seer like this: `#include <cstdio>  std::rename("C:\\Users\\exampleuser\\Desktop\\Test.docx", "C:\\Users\\exampleuser\\OneDrive\\examplefolder\\Test.docx");`  Also look at the Win32 [`MoveFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefile) API, eg: `#include <windows.h>  MoveFileA("C:\\Users\\exampleuser\\Desktop\\Test.docx", "C:\\Users\\exampleuser\\OneDrive\\examplefolder\\Test.docx");`

Comment: I am using OneDrive, but not uploading straight to it at this stage, I am just moving the files into the onedrive sync folde